# avoid auto release of NSMutable array..... iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray

I have a NSmutablearray
after i read datas from it, i cant read the same data(index) again

**Error:
"EXC_BAD_ACCESS"**

**in interface**

```
NSMutableArray *ticketList;


@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ticketList;
```

**assigning value**

```
self.ticketList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[results objectForKey:@"tickets"]];
```

**reading value**

```
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ticketCell";
    ticketCell *cell = (ticketCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    if (cell == nil) {

        [self.cellNib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = tmpCell;
        self.tmpCell = nil;



    }
    else {
        // Nothing to do here. Because in either way we change the values of the cell later.
    }

    cell.useDarkBackground = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0);
        // Configure the data for the cell.
    int rowID = indexPath.row;

        NSDictionary *currentTicket = [ticketList objectAtIndex:(int)(indexPath.row)];
    NSString *tikid = [currentTicket objectForKey:@"number"];
        cell.ticketID = [currentTicket objectForKey:@"number"];
        cell.ticketStatus = [currentTicket objectForKey:@"status"];
        cell.ticketOpenDate = [currentTicket objectForKey:@"oDate"];
        cell.ticketEndDate = [currentTicket objectForKey:@"eDate"];
        cell.ticketCategory = [currentTicket objectForKey:@"category"];
        cell.ticketPriority = [currentTicket objectForKey:@"priority"];
        cell.ticketInfo = [currentTicket objectForKey:@"info"]; 
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: did you run Instruments with Zombie tool? this shows exactly how "Zombie accesses" (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) happens!

Comment: You can confirm by putting a breakpoint where you read the value that ticketList is nil.

Comment: can you tell me how can i do that... i am new to obj-c/iOS

Comment: it isn't null. shows 12objects in side , but all are out of scope

Comment: i might be wrong... is it some thing to do with the cell!!
cos i get this error when i scroll up in table view(which loads previous cell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to alloc array properly:

```
ticketList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[results objectForKey:@"tickets"]];
```

And also maybe try to alloc currentTicket:

```
NSDictionary *currentTicket = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: check if `results` array is properly initailized and check for sure when exactly bad access is called, maybe there are more errors in your code

Comment: bad access is called at this point 
cell.ticketID = [currentTicket objectForKey:@"number"];

Comment: It's a blind guess, but maybe try to alloc currentTicket - `NSDictionary *currentTicket = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: OMG thank you soo much.. it worked :)

add this comment to your answer

Comment: Augh. This is so many kinds of wrong I can't even begin to address it.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
ticketList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[results objectForKey:@"tickets"]];
```

instead of

```
self.ticketList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[results objectForKey:@"tickets"]];
```

use this

```
NSDictionary *currentTicket = [ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

instead of

```
 NSDictionary *currentTicket = [ticketList objectAtIndex:(int)(indexPath.row)];
```

Comment: i changed it.. but still getting same errpr

Comment: [results objectForKey:@"tickets"] it returns array or anything

Comment: yes it returns array

my tableview loads all data with out error 
get this error only when i scroll(up) back

Comment: [ticketList retain];add this statement

Comment: Please ignore this advice. Do not randomly add `retain` calls. The property is already set to retain. Your problem is almost certainly one of over-releasing, not under-retaining.

Comment: @narayana changed to [ticketList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    still getting error

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like somewhere you're doing something like this:

```
[currentTicket release];
```

If so, don't. The `currentTicket` pointer doesn't belong to you.

Comment: @achiever One way or another, you are. At least, that's how the situation you describe would be likely to arise. It might conceivably be happening as a side effect of setting a property to `nil` or something, but you are killing the objects in the array.